# Fullcalendar 3.0 - Customize event content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, fullcalendar-3

I am using the lib fullcalendar(v3) https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3 and trying to customize the content of event.

I Would like todo something like this(green button):

[image]

I try with this CODE PEN:
https://codepen.io/williansmartins/pen/pobZMQj?editable=true&editors=001%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ffullcalendar.io%2F

The lib documentation tell is possible manipulate the **eventRender**, but I am not luck today.

```
  eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
      $el.popover({
        title: eventObj.title,
        content: eventObj.description,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body'
      });
    }
```

In fact I did, but using vanila javascript and the click is working only at the event and not on the button...

Comment: I got something, but not exactly, I add two buttons, but now I need to have diferents actions in each button, but the eventClick is only one. eventRender: function(event, element) {
          element.css("font-size", "1.2em");
          element.css("padding", "5px");
          element.html("<a class='btn btn-success'>button1</a> <a class='btn btn-danger'> button2</a> ");
        },

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
More than I needed.

First create the button using the eventRender, then compile again to AngularJS understand.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    const eventId = event.extra;
    
    element.html(event.title + `<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-success botao-extra extra1' ng-click='metodo1(${eventId})'>button1</a> <a class='btn btn-danger botao-extra extra2'  ng-click='metodo2(456)'> button2</a> `);
    $compile(element)($scope);
          
},
```

[image]